# Extract random ID from Json with multiple conditions

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can you please help me with a JMeter Json extractor to extract
Random rid with below conditions
rid !=0 and Name starts with "Test"
For Example: for below json we should retrieve rid 3 or 7 as it is not 0 and Name starts with "Test"

```
{
    "Documents": [
        {
            "rId": 0,
            "Name": "Test_Sunil",
        }, 
        {
            "rid": 3,
            "Name": "Test_Sunil",
        }, 
        {
            "rid": 7,
            "Name": "Test_Kumar",
        }
        {
            "rid": "0",
            "Name": "Unknown",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) and the following [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression:

```
$..Documents[?(@.rId != 0 && @.Name=~ /Test.*/)].rid
```

[image]

Full configuration:

[image]

Refer extracted value as `${rid}` later on where required.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, It works like a charm. Good learnings from you :)